# Definition of an invariant differential of an elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am somewhat confused by the definition of the invariant differentials in J. Silverman's book *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with Weierstrass equation $F(x,y)=0$. Then the invariant differential corresponding to the Weierstrass equation is defined as
$$\omega = \frac{dx}{2y+a_1x+a_3},$$
where the $a_i$ are as usual the coefficients of $F(x,y)$.

However, in formulation of various theorems, for example Theorem 5.2. on page 77, the notion of an invariant differential is used for a general elliptic curve, without explicit reference to any particular Weierstrass equation.

Another example is Proposition 1.1. in the book *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic curves*. Here is claimed that any two invariant differentials on the elliptic curve $E_\Lambda$ are scalar multiples of one another. But strictly speaking we have defined only one invariant differential on $E_\Lambda$

Thus given an elliptic curve $E$, what is meant by *an invariant differential* on $E$?

Comment: The invariant differential is defined by Silverman for a Weierstrass equation, not for an elliptic curve. However it follows from the formulas in Table 3.1 (last line) that for any two Weierstrass equations describing a given elliptic curve $E$, the associated invariant differentials will be scalar multiples of one another. (Alternatively, it also follows immediately from Proposition III.1.5.)

Comment: Are you aware that the space of differential forms on $E$ (relative to the base field) is 1-dimensional? "invariant" is a red herring here.

Comment: I really like @abx 's comment.  Since the space of differentials is 1-D, any differential is invariant under any action.

Comment: The previous comments are absolutely correct but also, an invariant differential is a differential form on the elliptic curve that is invariant under translation. It turns out that any global holomorphic differential form on an abelian variety is invariant.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82597/geometric-picture-of-invariant-differential-of-an-elliptic-curve?rq=1