# Nascent formal group law

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, ho.history-overview, power-series

$\DeclareMathOperator\FGL{FGL}$The formal group law (cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group_law), Ex. 1.6 of [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal+group), [Hazewinkel](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1979__63__73_0/)) derived from an analytic function or formal series $f(x) = x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + ...$ and its formal compositional inverse, perhaps derived from Lagrange inversion, $f^{(-1)}(x)$ is defined by

$$\FGL(x,y) = f[f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y)]$$.

I'm interested in earlier investigations of this formula and the closely related formula

$$F(x,t)=\exp[t \cdot g(x)d/dx]x = f[f^{-1}(x)+t],$$

where $g(x) = [df^{(-1)}/dx]^{-1}.$

Both occasionally pop up in MO (see [Q1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291888/characterizing-positivity-of-formal-group-laws), [Q2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52241/formal-group-laws-and-l-series), [O3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145555/why-is-there-a-connection-between-enumerative-geometry-and-nonlinear-waves/181534#181534)).

(Edit 9/19/22: In "[Coefficient rings of formal group laws](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291390921_Coefficient_rings_of_formal_group_laws)", Buchstaber and Ustinov give a nice presentation of some history of FGLs and their applications in algebraic geometry, algebraic topology, and mathematical physics.)

So far the earliest presentations I know of are

1. by Abel for the $\FGL(x,y)$ in 1826 (cf. "[From Abel's heritage: Transcendental objects in algebraic geometry and their algebraization](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307068)" by F. Catanese, p. 6, Thm. 2.1, and "[The Work of Niels Henrik Abel](http://www.abelprisen.no/c53052/binfil/download.php?tid=53200)" by Houzel, p. 24, Eqn. 5.)
2. by Abel for $F(x,t)$ in 1826 (cf. [Abel equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation), 1826).
3. by Charles Graves for $F(x,t)$ in 1853 in  "A generalization of the symbolic statement of Taylor's theorem" in the Proceedings of the Royal Irish Academy, Vol. 5, (1850-1853), p. 285-287 (cf. p. 13 in [The Theory of Linear Operators](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000616955) ... , Principia Press, 1936, by Harold T. Davis and MO-[Q4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214927/important-formulas-in-combinatorics/215203#215203)).

Aware of any earlier presentations than Abel's or Graves?

Comment: Hazewinkel link is to "On formal groups. The functional equation lemma and some of its applications."

Comment: Inselberg in "Superpositions of nonlinear operators. I. Strong superpositions and linearizability" on p. 502 states,  "Abel in 1826 <ref below> was the first to show that if $F(x, y)$ is an abelian group operation on the reals and satisfies certain other conditions, then there exist a one-to-one function, $f$, of one variable such that
$F(x, y) = f^{ -1}( f (x) + f(y))$."

Comment: N. H. Abel, Recherche de fonctions de deux quantites variable independantes
x et y, telles que $f(x, y)$, qui ont la propriM que $f(z,f(x, y))$ est une fonction symttrique de $z, x$ et $y$, J. Reine Angew. Math. 1 (1826), 11-15 [Oeuvres completes, I, pp. 61-65, Christiania 1881].